# Objects hides when drawing in full size

Tags: objects

[image: Hiding object]

Objects partially hides when are modeled in full size. These ar 900mm high. It happens in every view.

Answer (score 0):

you may have pressed CTRL+B instead of B when tryed to select. this clips the wiew to the rectangle area you draw after the keystroke. Try CTRL+B again to remove it.